# If the set of homomorphisms from a group $G$ to a group $H$ is in bijection with $H$ for any $H$, does $G = \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is not so hard to show that a homomorphism from the integers to a group $H$ must be of the form 
$$f(m) = x^m \quad \text{ for some } x \in H$$
Consequently, we get a one-to-one correspondence between $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, H)$ and $H$ itself (note that I'm using $\text{Hom}(G, H)$ to mean the set here; I'm not implying it has a group structure). However, I'm wondering if the converse is true: if $\text{Hom}(G, H)$ is bijective with $H$ for *any* group $H$, must we have $G = \mathbb{Z}$?

To prove this, I thought I'd show $G$ has to be infinite and cyclic. I got the infinite part; if we take $H = \mathbb{Z}_p$, then choose any nontrivial homomorphism $f$ (which must exist since $p > 1$) and any $g \in G$ that does not get sent to the identity under $f$, and we get
$$\{f(g), f(g^2),\ldots, f(g^p)\}$$
are all distinct. Thus, so are $\{g, g^2,\ldots, g^p\}$, so $G$ contains elements of order at least $p$ for any $p$ and is thus infinite. However, I'm struggling to get that $G$ is cyclic (if it's even true!), and I'd be interested to see if anyone has any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you can assume that $G$ is a free group, since otherwise you can find a group $H$ with $Hom(G,H)=0$. Have you thought about this for free groups with two generators?

Comment: remark: if you insist that the bijection $\text{Hom}(G, H) = H$ be natural, then this is a consequence of Yoneda's lemma and has nothing to do with group theory. (Naturality in this context means that it if $H \to H_1$ is a map, then the induced map $\text{Hom}(G, H) \to \text{Hom}(G, H_1)$ be equivalent to the induced map $H \to H_1$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking simply about set bijections, then the answer is no.

**Lemma**: If $H$ is finite then $\mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Q,H)$ contains only the constant homomorphism.

**Proof**: Let $s=\#H$. If $f\in \mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Q,H)$, then for any $q\in\Bbb Q$,
$$
f(q) = f\big( s\tfrac qs\big) = s f\big( \tfrac qs\big) = e
$$
since the element $f\big( \tfrac qs\big)$ is annihilated by the cardinality $s$ of $H$.

Then, since $\mathop{\rm Hom}(A\times B,H) \cong \mathop{\rm Hom}(A,H)\times \mathop{\rm Hom}(B,H)$, we see that $\mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q,H) \cong \mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Z,H) \cong H$ when $H$ is finite; on the other hand, when $H$ is infinite then $\mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q,H)$ contains a copy of $\mathop{\rm Hom}(\Bbb Z,H)$ which is also infinite.